# Copy all .jpg from subfolders to a single folder by cmd

Tags: cmd

I have a folder that has 148 folders in it, and in each of these folders they have a .jpg file. I need to get all these .jpg and put in a single folder

each folder is at least 1 .jpg

I can do this on Linux as well

```
`#!/bin/bash

for file in `find source -name * .jpg`;
of the mv "$ file" Destination;
 done;
```

but I can not play this in Windows. Only the find command that I can reproduce the same result: `dir /S /B *.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r %f in (*.jpg) do move %f %destination%
```

Note: This is the interactive version. In a command script, you need to protect the %f's from too-early variable substitution.

```
for /r %%f in (*.jpg) do move %%f %destination%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using PowerShell. When you see that the files are being moved as you expect, remove the `WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.jpg' |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\the\other\dir' -WhatIf }
```

You can run this in a cmd.exe shell or .bat script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.jpg' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\the\other\dir' -WhatIf }"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is in Windows is to open to root folder with the `Windows Explorer` at which you want to start searching all the elements. Then go to the small input field for searching and enter `*.jpg` the result will show all the `jpg` in the root folder and all subfolders. Then you can simply copy and paste the files to your destination folder.